# IIS Sub Application Unable to Read Web.Config

Tags: web-config, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a website setup in IIS that has an application within it. For whatever reason, IIS can't access the web.config of this sub application. Looking in the website directory, the config file is right where it should be.

If I try to edit (through IIS manager) any configurations of the sub application I get the following error:

[image]

The file path in the error notification is correct, except for '\\?\' appended to the beginning.

The parent website web.config has no issues, and can be configured through IIS.

What could be causing this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might have forgotten to install some OOB components, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/oob-500.html

Comment: Yes, that was it. Installed 'IIS URL Rewrite Module 2' and the problem went away. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to install the component IIS URL Rewrite Module 2. Once this was in place, the web.config was consumed properly.